# Simple HTML file sharing issue?

Tags: notepad++, html, source-code-protection

I recently created an html file in notepad++. This may be an amateur question, but how can I send the file via email to a friend without them being able to access the code, just the webpage if they run it? It is not published as a website, just a .html file. I dont want them to be able to take and change the webpage coding and claim for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible.   Webpages are always readable - visit any site on the web, right-click your mouse, View Page Source.   You can view all the source code.

As HTML files (web pages) are readable, you cannot send a page to someone and have it usable, while also not have it readable.

Answer (score 0):

well you will need to print it as pdf then, make a screenshot or something like that
there are html encoders on the web but of course if the browser can encode it back a other program can do that to.

Comment: Would they be able to access the javascript functions if it was just saved as a pdf

Comment: This answer is just incorrect.   The OP said they should be able to "run" the webpage...  saving it as a PDF completely negates this option.

Comment: @ttmcl98 they would not be able to access any functions, as there would not be any.  A PDF is not a webpage, and will only be a "picture" of what your website contained.   It will not be usable in any way.

Comment: @Charlie74 yes this was my understanding of the PDF, thank you for the clearing.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the file and use this on it:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/encrypter.htm

Unfortunately, this isn't going to 100% safeguard your code. Sending them the file IS sending them your code. The only completely fool-proof way is to screenshot and send that instead.

Comment: and the same link gives a decompiler so you can go back to the original source